# While executing/running google Dataflow job getting invalid parameters message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run command --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Word_Count --parameters inputFile=gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt,outputFile=gs://commad3421/output/my_output
```

While executing  above command through cloud shell, getting below error

Error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The template
>   parameters are invalid.
>   - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.dataflow.v1beta3.InvalidTemplateParameters 
>   parameterViolations:
>     - description: Missing required parameter
>       parameter: output
>     - description: Unrecognized parameter
>       parameter: outputFile

Answer (score 2):

Your `--parameters` is incorrect. It should be:

```
--parameters inputFile=gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt,output=gs://commad3421/output/my_output
```